# Eclipse: Customized folding

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse has built-in support for folding class/method definitions. But if/else, brackets and other blocks cannot be folded by default. I looked at the preference page, but there seems to be no rule to fold these elements. I'm wondering is it possible to define custom rules?

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge and I do not see that feature in the upcoming Helios 3.6 either.

I only saw folding for `if-else` block in CDT (C/C++ editor) with [bug 174597](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=174597)